# Dependency Preserving Decomposition?

Tags: database, attributes, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I am working on a textbook question and it asks the following:

> Let `R(A,B,C,D,E)` be decomposed into relations with the following three sets of attributes:
>
> ```
> {A,B,C} , {B,C,D}, {A,C,E}
> ```
>
> For each of the following sets of functional dependencies, determine if the dependencies  are preserved by the decomposition.
>
> ```
> AC -> E and BC -> D
> ```

How do I solve this?
The textbook doesn't provide a clear enough explanation on dependency preserving.

Answer (score 4):

**R** = {A,B,C,D,E} decomposed into **R<sub>1</sub>** ={A,B,C} , **R<sub>2</sub>** ={B,C,D} and **R<sub>3</sub>** ={A,C,E}.

*"determine if the dependencies are preserved by the decomposition."*

Yes they are as BC->D is preserved in **R<sub>2</sub>** and AC->E is preserved in **R<sub>3</sub>** as is very apparent!
**Note** - Although a decomposition may be *dependency-preserving* it is not necessary that it is in a higher normal form.

There is an easy method to check whether a decomposition is dependency-preserving. Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PL009B833078C3C571&v=9PZzyMhQViw) video.